# Visual C++ - call conversion operator on a primitive type explicitly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, operators

I was playing around with a class `Foo`, that defined an implicit `operator bool()`. I used `Foo` as a return type for several functions, so I could get an information about what had been done and call the `Foo::operator bool()` to get whether the operation had performed successfully.

Out of curiosity, I also tried an explicit call of the conversion operator while using `Foo`:

```
if(!func().operator bool()) // func returned Foo
    throw std::logic_error("operation was not successful");
```

That worked fine. Then, I suddenly decided to dump the `Foo` class and go with simple `bool` but I forgot to remove `.operator bool()` call on the function return value. And so I discovered a set of strange behaviors of Visual C++ 12.0 compiler (Visual Studio 2013).

---

None of the explicit calls of conversion operators to `bool` are valid in GCC:
`request for member ‘operator bool’ in ‘true’, which is of non-class type ‘bool’`

Now, the behavior I get with Visual Studio:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

bool func()
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    bool b = true.operator bool();
    cout << b << endl; // error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'b' used

    // evaluates to true (probably like b would do if it compiled)
    if(false.operator bool())
        cout << "a" << endl;

    cout << func().operator bool() << endl; // prints nothing

    int m = 10;
    cout << m.operator int() << endl; // prints nothing

    // correctly gives error: left of '.<' must have class/struct/union
    cout << m.operator <(10) << endl;
}
```

Even the intellisense is right and shows `Error: expression must have a class type`.
Is there an explanation to all this? A bug? An (unwanted) extension? What is it?

Comment: It *shouldn't* compile, and is probably a bug in the compiler. From a pure syntax perspective the code is correct, but the semantics isn't and should lead to an error.

Comment: Nothing [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx)

Comment: Reign of nonsense: `bool b = false.operator int;` is nicely accepted. And b is **true** : )

Comment: The strangest thing is that you had an explicit `.operator bool()` to forget removing in the first place

Comment: @molbdnilo That was just a test.

Comment: The same strange behaviour is present in Visual C++ 2015 CTP6. You should report this on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice find! The standard definitely makes this ill-formed with a diagnostic required, [expr.ref]:

> A postfix expression followed by a dot `.` or an arrow `->`,
>   optionally followed by the keyword `template` (14.2), and then
>   followed by an *id-expression*, is a postfix expression. [..] **For
>   the first option (dot) the first expression shall have complete class
>   type.**

Also, not an extension: Would be one hell of a nonsensical extension. It seems that VC++ implements `bool` with some [internal (class-like?) type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf4dy80a.aspx):

> In Visual C++ 5.0 and later, `bool` is implemented as a built-in type
>   with a size of 1 byte.

That type's class-like semantics are apparently not fully suppressed. Even

```
bool b;
b.operator std::string();
```

compiles ([giving a seemingly empty `string`](http://rextester.com/ARSUL10396)), implying that the internal class has a conversion operator template.